# How to edit word file content and download the new word file with react?

Tags: reactjs, xml, document, docx, cpu-word

I have a react app that communicates with a strapi backend. The objective is to be able to make a request to strapi to obtain a word file that resides there, obtain this file, modify its content and download it.

I have been trying many things without success and I have decided to do bisect, currently my goal is to get the arrayBuffer from word, modify it to xml and return it to arrayBuffer so that I can download it. When I do this, the content loses characters and the word document stops working saying that it has non-readable characters.

This is the fetch that I'm doing to strapi:

```
export async function getDocumentsByUrlApi(auth, urlValue) {
  try {
    const url = `${API_URL}${urlValue}`;
    console.log(url);
    const params = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type":
          "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`,
      },
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, params);
    const resultBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
    const resultText = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(resultBuffer);
    console.log("result Buffer = ", resultBuffer);
    console.log("result Text = ", resultText);

    return resultBuffer;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I recieve correctly my arrayBuffer and I can download it with any problem using this function. I've saved the arrayBuffer to the `rawDocument` variable:

```
const reader = new FileReader();

  const file = new Blob([rawDocument], {
  type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
  });
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  const fileConverted = new Blob([file], {
  type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
  });
  const element = document.createElement("a");
  element.href = URL.createObjectURL(fileConverted);
  element.download = "file_Document_to_download.docx";
  element.click();
```

The kind of word I will recieve is like a template to fill the gaps:

```
Hello{{firstname}} {{lastname}}, how are you?
amazing lastname: {{lastname}}.
see you!

regards,
```

But when I try to edit the array buffer, I create a document without full word characters, so I can't download a word to be opened.

```
 const reader = new FileReader();

   const file = new Blob([rawDocument], {
   type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
   });
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
   console.log("raw Document = ", rawDocument);
   const contentConverted = arrayBufferToContent(rawDocument);
   console.log("contentConverted = ", contentConverted);
   const contentToArray = contentToArrayBuffer(contentConverted)
   const fileConverted = new Blob([contentToArray], {
   type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
   });
   const element = document.createElement("a");
   element.href = URL.createObjectURL(fileConverted);
   element.download = "file_Document_to_download.docx";
   element.click();
```

These are my functions:

```
 function contentToArrayBuffer(content) {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const uint8array = encoder.encode(content);
    const arrayBuffer = uint8array.buffer;
    return arrayBuffer;
   }

   function arrayBufferToContent(arrayBuffer) {
    const uint8array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    const content = decoder.decode(uint8array);
    return content;
   }
```

Is there any way to get the word file body, modify it and download as word file which I can open?